# Creating a generic class where the parameter is an array

Tags: java, arrays, generics, comparator

I want to create a class that exends Comparator. This comparator will compare two arrays, where the arrays can contain anything that is comparable. Something that would let me do things like this:

```
comparator.compare(new Integer[] {1,2}, new Integer[] {3,4,5});
```

the type of the parameters are not necessarily Integer[]. They could be an array of anything.

Is there any way I can create such a class using generics? Or should my comparator receive objects instead. If it must receive objects, how can I check if it is an array and get elements from inside it?

Comment: What do you want the comparator to do? Compare each element?

Comment: Yeah. I search for a apache-commons to do that, but couldn't find one, so I'm implementing my own. Any suggestions regarding a pre-made one will help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using the array itself as the type parameter to `Comparator`?

```
public class ArrayComparator<T extends Comparable<? super T>> implements
        Comparator<T[]> {
    @Override
    public int compare(T[] o1, T[] o2) {
        // TODO
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your Comparator parameter type should be T[].

Here's an example usage:

```
public class Test<T> implements java.util.Comparator<T[]> {

    @Override
    public int compare(T[] paramT1, T[] paramT2) {
        return 0;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new Test<Integer>().compare(new Integer[] {1,2}, new Integer[] {3,4,5}));
    }

}
```

Comment: I think the OP needed the elements of the array to be `Comparable` to themselves.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, for example like this:

```
implements Comparator<T[]> {
    @Override
    public int compare(T[] array1, T[] array2) {
        //compare arrays here
        return ...;
    }
```

or a compare method like this that will infer the type on the calling values:

```
public static <T> int compare(T[] array1, T[] array2) {
```

Comment: Sure you can, but depends on exact usage of the class, would have to specify it at some point... `A<T> implements Comparator<T[]> {...` then have to specify it like: `new A<Integer>` or `extends A<Integer>` or similar

Comment: Umm @Vulcan... I pasted it directly from Eclipse, I (usually) always test first and did so this time as well. Maybe that's why Chip removed his comment?

Comment: Great two commenters (Chip and Vulcan) removed their comments so it now looks like a monologue here :)

Comment: I think the OP needed the elements of the array to be `Comparable` to themselves.

Comment: sure just change the `T` to: `T extends Comparable` as others have suggested by now.

Comment: @Pulsar I removed my incorrect comment before you posted a response to it.